# How to grep different strings followed by a tab on multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

Apologies, I could not find an answer that worked for me.
Working on a Win10 machine with Cygwin and/or Gitbash, I have a file of sequence read names ("readsfile") followed by other information all separated by tabs. The reads file looks like this:

```
NB501827:133:HMV5HAFX2:1:11101:3747:1066    75  NODE_622711+_length_75_cov_990.55   100.000 43
NB501827:133:HMV5HAFX2:1:11101:8852:1068    74  NODE_622752+_length_4244_cov_356.337    100.000 74
```

I want to simply use  `grep` to parse out the read names up to the first tab of each line, outputting the results to a separate file "readnames.txt". Not including the "tab" character would be a plus, but is fixable later. The output file "readnames.txt" should be:

```
NB501827:133:HMV5HAFX2:1:11101:3747:1066
NB501827:133:HMV5HAFX2:1:11101:3747:1066
NB501827:133:HMV5HAFX2:1:11101:8852:1068
```

(For now, the duplicated read names are okay)
I have tried a multitude of solutions found on this site. Some examples taking into account grep vs egrep vs grep -E, vs Perl grep include:

```
grep -oE $'^*\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
egrep '^NB*\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -oE '^NB'$'\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -oP 'NB*\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -o $'NB*\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -oE ^NB*$'\t' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -o '[NB*|[[:space:]]]' readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -o ^NB*[[:space:]] readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -o $"NB*$'\t'" readsfile > readnames.txt
grep -o \<NB*\> readsfile > readnames.txt
```

Note that I have also used scripts to include "actual" tabs using `<Cntrl-V><tab>`
or `grep -oE '^NB*    ' readsfile > readnames.txt` or `grep -oE '^NB.*    ' readsfile > readnames.txt` in most of the combinations used at the command line.

Also some other unsuccessful solutions:

```
sed -n 's/NB*\t/&/p' readsfile > readnames.txt
sed -n 's/*\t/&/p' readsfile > readnames.txt
```

I suspect this has been done but help is needed. Thank-you.

Comment: You certain there are no windows line endings on those files?

Comment: Yes. Files were created in CentOS7 and I checked for Windows EOL already

Comment: What about awk? have you tried it? `awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}' readsfile`

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f1 readsfile | uniq` might do it also?

Comment: That absolutely worked perfectly on my test files. Thank you! I'm not familiar with the awk commands you used however.

Comment: this site s.o. has a ton of entries for extracting the first unique field/column in a file. just search for it.

Comment: The `cut` solution did not work. It returned the entire lines of the readnames file

Comment: I did search, please believe me. Hours of searching and attempts. I must not have been using good keywords.

Comment: cut defaults to tabs as field separator, `-d ' '` would set it to space, this one is just a simple `cut -f1 readsfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything past the first tab removed including the tab, this sed would do that `sed 's/\t.*//g'`

Alternatively, `sed 's/\([^\t]*\)\t.*/\1/g'` finds any non-tab character repeated any number of times, followed by a tab and any number of characters, captures the bit up to the first tab, and spits that out.

`awk` handles tab delimited input very well too. `awk -F'\t' '!a[$1]++ {print}'` will print out the deduped first field (delimited by tabs) for each line.  This works by inserting and incrementing the value of an array keyed off the first field, so the first time it's encountered it evaluates to !0, so print is fired, and each subsequent time a value is seen it will be !1, !2, etc, evaluating to false and not printing.

Comment: Yes! your `sed` solution worked perfectly also. To be fair, @Jetchisel answered first. Both are answers. Which should I mark as the answer?

Comment: @hoytpr, I did not post an answer, just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what [zzevannn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67234420/451601) says, **awk** is your friend whenever you have column delimited by something that can be described with a regular expression.

In this particular case,

```
$ awk '{print $1}' filename > newfile
```

does what you want.  By default, awk separates fields on whitespace, and your first field has no whitespace, so you're golden.  If it did, you could use awk's **-F** option to tell it to break on a tab, or something else.

The clue to your difficulty for me was

> I want to simply use grep to parse out the read names

**grep**(1) will *find* things, but it won't parse: it won't change the line or output part of it.

To print the 1st field only the first time it's encountered, I would use

```
$ awk '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' filename > newfile
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $1}' filename | uniq > newfile
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $1}' filename | sort | uniq > newfile
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $1}' filename | sort -u > newfile
```

depending on the phase of the moon.  ;-)